# Java Socket - Not Accept a New Clients after time

Tags: java, time, client

Esteemed,

I need help configuring my server not to accept new connections after a certain amount of time.

Existing connections will remain, but will not accept new ones.

Java Socket.
Not Accept a New Clients after time

Comment: Check the time in the code where you listen for connections?

Comment: Your suggestion worked. But how do I get back to the client that the connection was refused?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.